# data.frame com hierarquia para lista aninhada no R

Tags: r

Tenho o seguinte `data.frame` `d`:

```
x <- data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=letters[4:6], c=letters[7:9], stringsAsFactors=F)
d <- tidyr::expand(x)
d

Source: local data frame [27 x 3]

   a b c
1  a d g
2  a d h
3  a d i
4  a e g
5  a e h
6  a e i
7  a f g
8  a f h
9  a f i
10 b d g
11 b d h
12 b d i
13 b e g
14 b e h
15 b e i
16 b f g
17 b f h
18 b f i
19 c d g
20 c d h
21 c d i
22 c e g
23 c e h
24 c e i
25 c f g
26 c f h
27 c f i
```

Eu gostaria de obter uma lista aninhada assim (para trabalhar com JSON e coisas do tipo):

```
$a
$a$d
[1] "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i"
$a$e
[1] "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i"
$a$f
[1] "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i"

$b
$b$d
[1] "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i"
$b$e
[1] "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i"
$b$f
[1] "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i"

$c
$c$d
[1] "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i"
$c$e
[1] "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i"    
$c$f
[1] "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i" "g" "h" "i"
```

Para fazer isso, usei a função `tree` abaixo

```
tree <- function(d) {
  aux <- with(d, split(b, list(a)))
  res <- lapply(aux, function(x) with(d, split(c, list(x))))
  res
}
```

Agora, digamos que eu tenha um `data.frame` hierárquico com `n` colunas. Como faço para criar uma lista aninhada?

Obrigado!

**Perguntas relacionadas**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247108/problems-splitting-data-frame-into-a-nested-list
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951334/hierarchical-data-frame-to-json-with-irregular-nodes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma solução usando recursão seria:

```
rec_split <- function(df){
 if(ncol(df) == 2){
  l <- split(df[[2]], df[[1]])
 }else{
   l <- split(df[-1], df[[1]])
   lapply(l, rec_split)
 }
}
```

Exemplo:

```
rec_split(d)
$a
$a$d
[1] "g" "h" "i"
$a$e
[1] "g" "h" "i"
$a$f
[1] "g" "h" "i"

$b
$b$d
[1] "g" "h" "i"
$b$e
[1] "g" "h" "i"
$b$f
[1] "g" "h" "i"

$c
$c$d
[1] "g" "h" "i"
$c$e
[1] "g" "h" "i"
$c$f
[1] "g" "h" "i"
```

Comment: Pela navalha de occam, sua solucao é equivalente e usa menos recursos então vou colocar como aceita. Mas acho que a solução do Evandro Dalbem é ótima; inclusive daria pra usar para outros problemas mais complexos.

Answer (score 4):

A maior parte do processo você já fez. Falta apenas alguma estrutura que permita fazer isto de forma recursiva até a penúltima coluna (e a última seria um vetor dos resultados, pelo que entendi). 
Esta aqui me pareceu uma solução engenhosa para o seu problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539026/split-data-frame-apply-function-and-return-results-in-a-nested-list

```
library(plyr)

nested.dlply <- function(df, by, fun, ...) {
   if (length(by) == 1) {
      dlply(df, by, fun, ...)
   } else {
      dlply(df, by[1], nested.dlply, by[-1], fun, ...)
   }
}

x <- data.frame(a=letters[1:3], b=letters[4:6], c=letters[7:9], stringsAsFactors=F)
d <- tidyr::expand(x)

var.names <- names(d)
n <- length(var.names)
d.list <- nested.dlply(d, var.names[-n], function(x)x[, var.names[n]])

jsonlite::toJSON(d.list, pretty=TRUE) # Se quiser transformar num JSON
```

E o resultado fica

```
> d.list$a
$d
[1] "g" "h" "i"

$e
[1] "g" "h" "i"

$f
[1] "g" "h" "i"
```

Dá para melhorar a forma de fazer isso, por exemplo no código acima estou acessando um objeto fora do escopo da função anônima que irá retornar a última coluna para a lista aninhada.

Comment: Obrigado! não tinha pensado em usar recursão!